# Bostock's d3 Object Constancy example: what is effect of d3.transition().each?

Tags: d3.js, each, transition, duration

Complete fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbrown0001/o7qL4dpr/

I'm trying to emulate Mike Bostock's object constancy example https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/, and I can't figure out what is selected by the `each()` on his line line 133:

```
function change() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  d3.transition()
    .duration(altKey ? 7500 : 750)
    .each(redraw);
  }
```

I'm using what seems like the same construction in my fiddle example, and while it does seem to get the transition effect to run I don't see the slower duration. In general, what does this construct `d3.transition.each()` select in concrete specifics? It seems like it may be some kind of "master transition", but I can't see how the `each()` iteration is working. I must have some key difference but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like in your other question, this is something that has a lot to do with d3 v3 vs d3 v4. You will not be able to reproduce the behaviour with this code in v4

Have a look at [this section](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#transitions-d3-transition) of the d3 v4 release notes where mbostock addresses the changes in transition.each :

> This method replaces the deeply magical behavior of transition.each in 3.x; in 4.0, transition.each is identical to selection.each

In v3, transition.each was different as documented here : https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#each

> [...] immediately invokes the specified function for each element in the current transition, passing in the current datum d and index i, with the this context of the current DOM element.

So basically the reason why it's not working the same way is that now, transition.each will loop through each element affected by the transition.

Comment: Nice answer! Very well researched. It's worth noting, that the *Object Constancy` example is still based on D3 **v2**, which won't affect your conclusions, though!

Comment: Ahh.. between being in the process of learning d3 and moving to v4 halfway through, I had a number of pieces "in the air". Answers to this and my other question have been extremely helpful. I don't feel so bad, as the areas I was confused are exactly the areas M. Bostock leads off his discussion in "What Makes Software Good" as areas where he wasn't happy with v3. :)

Comment: Yup, exactly. D3 is quite a lot to take in at first. Between "thinking in joins" and the d3 specific functions, it's not easy! Looks like you're doing great though